# how to make auto increment of string like ALG030001 in php

Tags: php

i want to split this id ALG030001 but it can't , please help me ,and make it auto increment using PHP like ALG030002,ALG030003,ALG030004,ALG030005,ALG030006 when user submit in database

Comment: This is really basic, isnt it? Even without the knowledge of the 'easy' way ancient geek posted: Split string, + operator, string concatenation. I think this is even too basic to be asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

    $num = 'ALG030001';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++)
    { 
        echo $num++ . "<br>";
    }


?>
```

Comment: Will this really work? Double plus operator on a mixed string?

Comment: @C4ud3x I  tested it and works !  PHP 5.5

Answer (score 0):

My first thought to solve this problem would get the part of the string that you have and change to something that you can actually increment, an *int* for example.

```
<?php
    $string = "ALG030001";
    $chars = substr($string,0,3);

    $number = (int) substr($string,3,strlen($string));

    for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
        $string = $chars.$number++; 

        echo $string;
    }
?>
```

There might be a better way to solve this, but in your case that should do.